# char pointer is struct array memory leak

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc, memory-leaks

I'm having memory leaks in a larger program and I believe this is the cause of it.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

typedef struct _struct{
    char* name;
} str;

int main() {
    system("PAUSE");

    str* Character = (str*)malloc(sizeof(str) * 20000);

    for(int i = 0; i < 20000; i++){
        Character[i].name = (char*)malloc(20000);   // Assign memory.
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 20000; i++){
        free(Character[i].name);            // Free memory.
    }

    free(Character);
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Memory at first pause: ~500K.

Memory at second pause: ~1.7M.

Using VS2012 for testing. Any ideas?

Comment: Your code looks correct.  How are you measuring memory use?  Is it possible your heap manager simply hasn't compressed its heap following your calls to `free`?  In this case, extra memory would be assigned to your process but wouldn't be in use by your program so would actually be available for other code to allocate.

Comment: When u use malloc, pls be sure to check if memory is actually allocated if (Character == NULL)

Comment: you shouldn't be casting the return from malloc. This is C and you can assign a void * to anything.

Comment: I also tried the c++ method and used new char[] as well as delete(). Same problem appears :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you measuring the amount of memory occupied by the program? One thing off the top of my head is that you're looking at the size of the working set the OS is keeping track of. Since you've allocated and freed a lot of memory, the size of that set has increased. Some OSs will adjust the size of the working set after a while, some won't. What OS are we looking at here?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate and memory usage from Task Manager

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what Windows does (will check later, or someone else might fill in) , but it probably doesn't show what you expect. Modern operating systems manage process memory in a gross and lazy way to save on processing and might delay the deallocation of pages. The implementation of malloc and free might be reserving memory too. If you really want to be sure, use a tool like valgrind to check for leaks.

Comment: I just ran it with DrMemory and it found 3 (1536 bytes) of possible leaks with 319 still reachable allocations.

Comment: @Marc: Are you sure those allocations come from your code? The code seems correct. What about a program that doesn't use `malloc` or `free` at all? What if you comment out the calls to `free`?

Comment: When `free` is commented out, there is a lot more memory allocated when the program ends. And for purpose in my main program I need to use `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: Test without calling `malloc` and `free` at all just to check if the problem is with your code.

Comment: I will do some more testing.

Comment: I see you've accepted the answer, but did you actually find out any new information?

Comment: Was an OS issue. Tested it on Linux and Windows, ran it in a loop and didn't affect final memory value along with different memory finishing values on Linux and Windows. (Sorry for late reply)

Answer (score 3):

When you call `malloc`, memory is allocated on the heap. If there is insufficient space left on the heap, the program will ask the OS for more memory and another chunk is acquired. Memory acquired from the OS is usually not returned until the program finishes (although this is up to the OS).

Program size alone can not normally be used to check for memory leaks! Use Valgrind or a similar tool to check for memory that never gets `free`d.

Answer (score -1):

str* Character = (str*)malloc(sizeof(str) * 20000);

In the above line you are allocating the memory by finding the size of the struct. Here the size of the structure you will get will be the size of the pointer width and not the size of the char.

suppose for example if the pointer width is 32 bit the it will allocate (4 * 20000) = 80000 bytes.

If you want to allocate for 20000 struct's,

str* Character = (str*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 20000);

Comment: str* Character is an array of structs, not characters (confusing name I can agree) so sizeof(str) is correct